# How to Show date in textbox which type is date in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net

How to Show date in textbox from database.TextBox type is "date". In asp.net

Comment: Are you trying to set it from the view (in the .aspx file) or from the backend program (the .cs or .vb file)?
Can you post some code?

Comment: _txtCoatOrderDate.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Coat_CUSTM_Date"].ToString();

Comment: this is the code which is in my .aspx.csfile

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question.

Comment: That's my TextBox:
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="_txtCoatOrderDate" type="date" CssClass="form-control" Style="display: inline-block;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


And that's my code :
_txtCoatOrderDate.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Coat_CUSTM_Date"].ToString();


Problem is that when i fetched date from database and shows that's date in this texbox nothing will show there

Answer (score 1):

As the experts said above, this one worked for me:

```
((DateTime)dr["columnName"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

or

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dr["columnName"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Try to re-format the date in the parentheses, it may be **(yyyy-MM-dd)** or **(dd-MM-yyyy)**

This one is working in 2023.

NOTE: I'm fetching the data from the database in a DataRow instead of DataTable, NOT because it works better, but because this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
_txtCoatOrderDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["Coat_CUSTM_Date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments,

Comment: the textbox has the type of date in which i want to show date which i fetched from database.

Comment: That's my TextBox: <asp:TextBox ID="_txtCoatOrderDate" type="date" CssClass="form-control" Style="display: inline-block;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  and you can see that its has the type date

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value to a datetime, then convert again to string.
Something like this:

```
_txtCoatOrderDate.Text = ((Datetime)dt.Rows[i]["Coat_CUSTM_Date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: the textbox has the type of date in which i want to show date which i fetched from database.

Comment: What's the format date are you expecting? (Ex.: dd-MM-yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy). When you tried the code above what happened?

Comment: When i try the above code its fetched the date from database but not shows in Textbox , date format is (MM/dd/yyyy)

Comment: Did you try with this format? .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

Comment: the problem is textbox has the type "Date" means there is a calendar  already in text box, but i want when date is fetched from database that's show in textbox

Comment: I know, but you can set the value in the text format, but the format must be the correct one. By the W3C standart is yyyy-MM-dd. If you already try the _txtCoatOrderDate.Text = ((Datetime)dt.Rows[i]["Coat_CUSTM_Date"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); then try with the standart: _txtCoatOrderDate.Text = ((Datetime)dt.Rows[i]["Coat_CUSTM_Date"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Yes I Tried it but nothing happens

Comment: Did you try with the standart? yyyy-MM-dd. I simulated here and works fine. Looking for others issues I found the same anwser. This is weird, must be working... =/

Answer (score 0):

i tried this its working

TextBox1.Text = ((DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Coat_CUSTM_Date"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Thanks RMH Sir